# JMeter thread properties clarification

Tags: testing, jmeter, load-testing

I am running a distributed load test with JMeter and need some clarification on these three settings: number of threads, ramp up period, and loop count.

Are the number of threads spread out across all servers in the JMeter cluster?  Say I have 4 JMeter servers and have these parameters:

```
num. of threads: 12
ramp up period: 1 sec. 
loop count: 1
```

In this scenario, will 12 threads be started on each server or 3?

Thank you,
Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter master simply runs the same script in all the nodes/clients.
Each machine creates 12 threads in 1 seconds. So, You will have 48 threads in 1 second with your setup.